# How to click-drag the contents of a frame with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, frame, drag, frameset

I am attempting to enable click-and-dragging (similar to the touch-drag interaction one might enjoy on an iPhone or an iPad) on a frame within an old-school frameset.

The functionality I'm looking for is similar to what is shown here:
http://jsfiddle.net/AhC87/2/

I achieved some small success with the jQuery nicescroll plugin but it does not support horizontal scrolling and seems rather buggy and inconsistent (e.g. continuing to scroll even after the click is released).

Here is the interface I am trying to enable this behavior in:
http://simrtk.net/map/map.php?x=258&y=176

The left-hand map interface can be scrolled using the minimap on the top-right hand side and all traditional scrolling methods work, but I thought it might be nice to enable a click-to-drag feature to make the process more enjoyable. I've also received requests to that effect. Any assistance at all would be highly appreciated!

Note: I used rickety old framesets for this because positioning the control sidebar over the map with CSS resulted in terrible performance on slower computers, so it probably isn't an option to ditch the frameset in this scenario.

Comment: your mini-map shows the entire world, so if you drag some of it you will have blank space in the minimap while dragging, is that what you want ?

Comment: So the link I shared is composed of two frames, #fmap, the map on the left-hand side, and #fcontrols, the menu on the right-hand side. What I would like to do is allow someone to click on the map (the contents of #fmap) and drag with the same limitations as they might expect through typical horizontal or vertical scrolling.

I also need to register regular clicks on the map (such as on one of those soldier guys to view more information about them).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to integrate the jsfiddle you mentioned, for that add the following javascript inside your `$(document).ready` code in the `map_large.js` file:

```
$("#map").mousedown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    down=true;
    x=e.pageX;
    y=e.pageY;
    top=$(this).scrollTop();
    left=$(this).scrollLeft();
});

$("body").mousemove(function(e){
    if(down){
        var newX=e.pageX;
        var newY=e.pageY;

        //console.log(y+", "+newY+", "+top+", "+(top+(newY-y)));

        $("#map").scrollTop(top-newY+y);    
        $("#map").scrollLeft(left-newX+x);    
    }
});

$("body").mouseup(function(e){down=false;});
```

Comment: I was messing around with this for a while. I must have messed up the containers. I added a container div and some JavaScript to populate the proper widths/heights needed and now the code above is starting to work. I've got two more problems:

Comment: 1) When you click and drag outside the dragging container (#map_window replacing #map in the example above) the dragging condition remains, allowing the map to scroll under the cursor when you return it to the map until you click.  
  
2) That information viewer which appears on a click should appear for a traditional click while a click and drag shouldn't prompt it.  

Do you have any suggestions for me? And thank you for your assistance!
  
Here's a new demo:  
http://simrtk.net/map/map_demo.php?x=258&y=176